# Looping SQL rows and sorting them

Tags: php, javascript, sql, loops

As it was pointed out in the answers, I was not looking to organize results, but to filter them. I'm sorry for the confusion! :D

I've tried my best to google my way out of this problem, but I'm having a very hard time finding a solution..

I have a SQL database with this structure, as I'm trying to make a basic CMS:

### pageid | title | pagetext | menu_par

What I want to do is make a navigation on the page, that loops all the rows and makes them look like links, which my teacher helped me with a few months back:

```
$query_MenuItems = "SELECT pageid,title,menu_par FROM v2 ORDER BY menu_par ASC";
$MenuItems = $mysqli->query($query_MenuItems);
$row_MenuItem = $MenuItems->fetch_assoc();
$totalRows_MenuItems = $MenuItems->num_rows;    

do { echo 
"<a href=\"?page={$row_MenuItem['pageid']}\">{$row_MenuItem['title']}</a><br/>";
} 
while ($row_MenuItem = $MenuItems->fetch_assoc());
}
```

This works fine, however my issue is that I have no idea how to sort the different links, based on what their menu_par value is.

I feel like I have tried everything in my power to fix this, and it is stressing me out

Is there any way I can make a similiar loop as the one above, but sorting it by using more than one?:

```
while ($row_MenuItem = $MenuItems->fetch_assoc())
{
if ("{$row_MenuItem['menu_par']}" == '1') echo
"<a href=\"?page={$row_MenuItem['id']}\">{$row_MenuItem['title']}</a><br/>";
}
```

I hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Can you 'select ... order by menu_par' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using `ORDER BY` in Your SQL query?

```
SELECT pageid,title,menu_par FROM v2 ORDER BY menu_par ASC
```

By this query (and the ORDER BY x ASC clause) the records are ordered by menu_par value in ascending order...

You can read more about this here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

If You want to filter the results instead depending on the `menu_par` value (e.g. You want to select just those links that has `menu_par == 1`) You would use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT pageid,title,menu_par FROM v2 WHERE menu_par = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, i didn't read the whole question but load all data and, then, sorting it into PHP doesn't seems a good idea.
DBMS are designed for that, and due to your query for retrive data, you should order them directly by doing something like that

```
SELECT pageid,title,menu_par FROM v2 order by menu_par
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer - but how do i then sort it so all the rows where menu_par = 1 will go into the menu1 code on the page?

Comment: You have them alredy sorted (order by option). By fetching all rows returned by query, you'll be able to read menu_par from record and then, thank to that value, you can insert it into any menu section of your page.

Comment: i am sorry if i'm being an idiot but i am still confused. I have ordered the select by menu_par, but lets say i want to put all the menu_par 1's into a certain <li> list on the page - what sort of loop would i use, and how would i make sure it only posted the right menu_pars?

Comment: You sould create dinamically your lists by appending your element into a while loop. That while will fetch (take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)) all records, then you should (i.e. by inserting it into a variable) check if the id of that record is changed. If it is, thne you should stop appending or append it to another list. However I can't help you more that this because I can't write - right now - the whole code...

Comment: i wouldnt want you to write the whole code, i really appreciate you explaining this :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in the database, using a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT pageid,title,menu_par FROM v2
WHERE menu_par = 1
```

Comment: You sure? Ordering data using `WHERE`?

Comment: Looking at the code sample he provided, I think what he actually means by sorting is filtering. He already have answers for Order by, so I took a wild guess.

Comment: Ah, I see... Maybe he was talking 'bout ordering but wanted to filter... We will see what comes out of him :-)

Comment: I guess filter does sound more like what i'm looking for - do you suggest that i make a query/select for each menu then?

Comment: If you have a reasonable amount of menus, then yes. If you want something more flexible (like if you want to filter your records according to an input from user), then no. So it depends on your requirement. 

I suggest you to do more reading on what you are capable of doing with SQL, and how to reflect it on your page using PHP. http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp might be a good start.

Comment: @shadyyx, It turns out he wanted to filter :p

Comment: @ErkanHaspulat OK, I edited my answer then to meet the desired result of the OP. :-)